# Invalid conversion from '`A**`' to '`void**`

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        A(int x){ a = x;}
        ~A();
    private:
        int a;
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new A(10);
    void** p;
    p = &a;
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling with **g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704** , I am getting following error :

> test.cpp: In function '`int main()`':
>   test.cpp:17: error: invalid conversion from '`A**`' to '`void**`'

Comment: Yes, getting the error is quite natural because the conversion is invalid without explicit casting. Then, what is your question?

Comment: p = static_cast<void**>(&a);
I casted it like above. And again i am getting following error :
error: invalid static_cast from type ?A**? to type ?void**?

Comment: This is a dangerous conversion. Consider what happens if you then do `*p = new int;`.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a `void**`?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to write some C API. and internally C++ implemnetation. Don't want to expose my internal type to user

Comment: Isn't that what *abstract data types* are for?

Comment: @vidhugangwar This conversion is so unsafe it needs `reinterpret_cast`, and you *really* need to know what you're doing. (Being confused by this usually indicates that you don't.)

Comment: @MikeCAT why explicit casting is not needed for below case

    A* a = new A(10);
    void* p;
    p = a;

Comment: [passing pointers from C to C++ and vice versa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076209/passing-pointers-from-c-to-c-and-vice-versa)

Comment: @vidhugangwar A `void*` points to `void`, which means it can point to anything. But a `void**` can only point to one thing - to a `void*`.

Comment: FWIW, conversions from `A**` to `void**` are necessary to use some APIs. For example, see [CoCreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one star to much. `void*` can already hold **any** pointer, without casts:

```
int main()
{
    A* a = new A(10);
    void* p;
    p = &a;
    return 0;
}
```

This works for multiple levels, even:

```
int main()
{
    A* a = new A(10);
    A** aa = &a;
    A*** aaa = &aa;
    void* p = &aaa;
}
```

This works because `A***` is a pointer to a `A**`.

Comment: While you're right, I have to ask, does it matter, wouldn't it be kinda helpful to maintain the level of indirection as part of the pointer type? Also wouldn't your code throw the same error, as it attempts to cast from a `A***` to a `void*`.

Comment: @JonathanMee: No, that's pretty much the point. `void*` can hold any type of pointer. `void**` holds a pointer to a `void*`. For that reason, you need **exactly** one * on `void*` here. Not 2 or 3, not 0, but 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just assign the value of one type (`A**`) to the variable of another one (`void**`), if it can't be [converted implicitly](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion). You need to [explicitly convert](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) value from one type to another:

```
class A
{
    public:
        A(int x){ a = x;}
        ~A();
    private:
        int a;
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new A(10);
    void** p;

    // use `reinterpret_cast'
    p = reinterpret_cast<void**>(&a);

    // C-style cast works but it is a bad practice in C++
    p = (void**)&a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you added the `reinterpret_cast` but you should really remove the C-Style cast all together. It just encourages bad coding practices.

Comment: Actually, this answer isn't really correct. You **can** assign a variable of some type *U* to a variable of some type *V* without a cast, as long as *U* can be implicitly converted to *V*. If *V* is `void*` then *U* can be **any** pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`reinterpret_cast`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823721/how-to-catch-the-null-pointer-exception):

> It is purely a compiler directive which instructs the compiler to treat the sequence of bits (object representation) of `expression` as if it had the type `new_type`.

In this case your `expression` will be `&a` which has the type `A**` and your `new_type` will have the type `void**`:

```
p = reinterpret_cast<void**>(&a);
```

Do have a care here as C++ isn't really that fond of the `void` type and your code is very likely going to violate [Type Aliasing Rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing).

In my mind a cast to `void**` is an indication that a template should probably be used. Without seeing your code I can't guarantee that, but, if you want to fill me in anymore in the comments perhaps I can help.