# compiling a "C" based lib in a C++11 project in VisualStudio

Tags: c, visual-studio, c++11

I'm trying to use a C based library into my C++ project. 
The C header files come already with

```
    extern c {...}
```

The problem is as soon as I add some includes which are C++11 based (like Thread, Chrono) it won't compile anymore and start complaining about the thread.h or chrono.h files!

I have also tried putting extern C in my includes but this did not help.

The project is in Visualstudio2015.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot include C++ files into a C program. You *can* do it the other way round and you *can* implement a strictly C header in a C++ program. You should develop the C library as a standalone first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16851023/193892  I think you may be helped by this. I also agree with what @quamrana said.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. @quamrana Well I am using the C headers inside C++ Project.

Comment: If you stick to calling C code from C++ you will be ok. I have also written an answer to a previous question which might be helpful here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2203593/4834

Comment: @quamrana you can, only if you restrict yourself to features that exist in both C and C++.

Comment: @Quentin: You can, what, exactly?

Comment: @quamrana what you described in your first comment (didn't notice the second one, sorry), that is write files compilable as either C or C++.