# c++ wrapper for header encapsulation

Tags: c++, c, wrapper, encapsulation

I am trying to write a wrapper class which wraps around another class containing c based header files and functions.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55651423/compiling-a-c-based-lib-in-a-c11-project-in-visualstudio) is the original problem to which I am trying to find a workaround.

This is the class which calls the c functions and should be encapsulated:

```cpp
#include "c_header.h"

class A
{
public:
          void foo () { 
          function();  //calling a function of the c based library
        }; 
};
```

Here is how I created the wrapper class (.lib) to encapsulate the class A :

```cpp
#include "A.h"
class wrapper  
{
public:
    void  test()
        {
          wa-> foo()
        };
private:
    A* wa;
};
```

And here is the test project in which I was hoping to call the wrapper class library without the need to know about the class A (c_header.h and its functions).

```cpp
#include "wrapper.h"

void main(){
    wrapper *w = new wrapper;
    w->test();
}
```

The test main does not compile and issues linker problems complaining about the functions inside class A (here *function()*).

The codes are in windows7 and visual studio2015.

Could anyone help me with really encapsulating/wrapping another class without the need for the header files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not the problem but `void main()` is not correct.  `main()` must always have an `int` return type.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.  Everyday they diverge more and more.  My 2 cents are: Write a `.h` header to be included in `.c` files, and another `.hpp` header with the same name to be included in `.cpp` files; even if 90% of the code is the same. You will need to maintain twice the code, but you will avoid most of the madness of handling two different languages in one file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the compiler/linker it's a C header:

```
extern "C" {
#include "c_header.h"
}
```