# Is it possible to implement an interface through inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

```
struct I { 
      virtual void foo() = 0; 
      virtual void bar() = 0;
};

struct A { 
        void foo(){};
 };
struct B: public A, public I {

     void bar(){};
};
```

Is this pseudo-code supposed to be valid in C++? Currently I am getting an undefined reference error for `foo()` at link time.

If this is not supposed to work, please recommend a technique to create an interface, which gets implemented by inheritance, as in the example.

Comment: Some whitespace never hurt :(

Comment: `foo` and `bar` shall have a return type. Did you mean `void`?

Comment: AFAIK `struct I` and `struct A` are gonna have distinct vtables, so it shouldn't work. But at least you should declare `A::foo()` virtual.

Comment: @black he stated it's pseudo-code

Comment: @GézaTörök: vtables are an implementation detail; the question is whether or not the language specifies that will work. And you'd only declare `A::foo` virtual if you wanted to override that - you almost certainly don't, if it's supposed to be a concrete implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "valid". You'll have to add the missing return types, and perhaps fix some other syntactic issues, to get it to compile.

If you mean, "is `B` a non-abstract class that correctly overrides both pure virtual functions declared in `I`?", then no. It doesn't override `foo`; inheriting a function of the same name does not count as overriding.

If you want `A::foo` to be the implementation of `I::foo`, then you'll have to add a wrapper in `B` to provide the override:

```
void foo() {A::foo();}  // assuming the missing return type is void
```

Comment: It's a pity I can't at least use `using A::foo;`.

Answer (score -1):

1. virtual functions cannot be inlined. You are inlining A::foo() and B:bar()
2. You are inheriting I from two paths in class B. Through A and directly through I. You will need to provide the implementation of foo() in class B as well.

Comment: Both wrong. Any function can have an inline definition, virtual or not. (Virtual function calls often can't be inlined, but that doesn't prevent inline definitions). `A` does not derive from anything, so `I` is only inherited once.

Comment: 2. ah , I didn't see A not inheriting I. so the second one is wrong. 1. But how come virtual functions definition be put in the header? The compiler will create a static function for each encounter in such cases

Comment: "The compiler will create a static function for each encounter in such cases" - no it won't. It will treat them exactly like any other inline function, allowing multiple definitions which are eventually resolved into a single one. That's what inlining is specified to do, for any function with external linkage, virtual or not.

Comment: I meant "multiple" for each compilation unit. Like one for each cpp file.

Comment: yes, inline functions can be defined in more than one translation unit, and the definitions are eventually resolved into a single one. That's what "inline" means, and it works for any function, virtual or not. To say that virtual functions can't be inline is simply wrong.

Comment: Your understanding of "inline is different from "Effective C++" book item - 30 

and also from this answer here which says "When a function is inline it has multiple definitions, one in each cpp file where it is referenced." as I expected.
[1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898094/why-c-virtual-function-defined-in-header-may-not-be-compiled-and-linked-in-vta

see section "stop inlining virtual methods"
[2] https://www.chromium.org/developers/coding-style/cpp-dos-and-donts

Comment: My understanding of "inline" is exactly the same as that. It means you can define the function multiple times, just as we both said. Your second link is someone's style guide, advising you not to inline virtual functions, if you want to reduce the amount of code in your headers, because there's often little or no benefit to inlining them. (The wording is dubious, and might be read as implying that they can't be defined inline, when the truth is just that calls to them can't be inlined). Your claim that they can't be defined inline is simply wrong. Please stop trying to say otherwise.