# How to bind a language to a C library

Tags: c, ruby, node.js, binding

Suppose I have a pure **C** library and I want to use it in Ruby or NodeJS. As far as I know, I should write a binding to the **C** library from my environment.

What I want to know is how this binding is possible and what the remedies are.

Comment: Have you even tried looking for this on Google: http://pravinchavan.wordpress.com/2013/11/08/c-binding-with-node-js/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use a C++ library from node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629677/how-can-i-use-a-c-library-from-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a C library from Ruby, you can use the [FFI](https://github.com/ffi/ffi) gem. It stands for Foreign Function Interface and seems to be doing what you want. There are [RubyTapas series](http://www.rubytapas.com/episodes) of episodes of how to use it.