# API wrapper to convert cpp to js

Tags: javascript, c++

I'm currently working on a JavaScript project and need assistance in creating a JavaScript API wrapper for the Steamworks SDK. The existing SDK is coded in C++, and I'm looking to convert it into JavaScript.

I've already explored the Steamworks SDK documentation and have a good understanding of how the C++ version works. However, my project requires the use of JavaScript, and I'm not familiar with the process of creating a wrapper or adapting C++ code for JavaScript.

Here is C++ code on how the Steamworks SDK works in the C++ side:

```cpp
#include "steam_api.h"

void InitializeSteam() {
    SteamAPI_Init();
    // Additional initialization code...
}
```

Therefore, I am asking guidance on how to create a JavaScript wrapper for the Steamworks SDK?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931827/how-to-call-a-c-method-from-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629677/how-can-i-use-a-c-library-from-node-js

Comment: *Are there any tools or libraries that can simplify this process?* Kiss of death. Remove this line because the question will be closed for asking for libraries/tools. If your problem is most easily fixed with a library or tool, someone will answer using that library or tool.

Comment: [Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/)?