# nodejs:How to call c++ DLL function through nodejs?

Tags: c++, node.js, dll

I have a windows c++ DLL. It provides some functions like add(1,2). But I don't have the source code for this DLL, is it possible call functions in this DLL through nodejs, I mean, through web side and http. If it possible, what should I do?

Comment: Maybe you can find some useful infor from this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629677/how-can-i-use-a-c-library-from-node-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629677/how-can-i-use-a-c-library-from-node-js)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use a C++ library from node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629677/how-can-i-use-a-c-library-from-node-js)

Answer (score 5):

Did you check out the ffi nodejs library? https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi

```
var ffi = require('ffi');

var libm = ffi.Library('libm', {
  'ceil': [ 'double', [ 'double' ] ]
});
libm.ceil(1.5); // 2
```

Comment: this isn't a good solution for most people

Comment: @Martian2049 could you explain why this isn't a good solution? It appears that this is a very popular library (15K weekly downloads). Could you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html
@WillEccles check out this document if you haven't. it's more complicated approach but more reliable.

Comment: i might be wrong about ffi library tho

Comment: The addons system is for when you're writing your own C++ code for use with Node.js, which is kinda useless when you're a JS dev who knows zero C++ and you just need to work with a .dll file that someone gave you. Then you want something like node-ffi, which _is itself an addon_ specifically designed to act as a call proxy (and, as it should, comes with a warning that you're on your own and you better know what you're doing because segfaults are now on you ;)

Comment: (Do note that this is a very old project by now, of course, and the odds that it still works with your preferred version of Node are almost zero)

Comment: node-ffi is not maintained from 2019. It doesn't work in Windows, node v16.17.0, npm v8.15.0. Npm can not install node modules at all!

Answer (score 1):

The
https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi
was indeed a good solution but not maintained since 2019.

The new version is:

https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/node-ffi-napi