# Can I run an executable file through javaScript?

Tags: javascript, c++, input

I am in the process of coding a board game with C++. After compiling, there will be an executable file that runs the game. I wish to call this executable from a JavaScript program I am creating to handle the input and output of the executable. Is it possible to run the executable from JavaScript?

I know there are other answers such as this one: [Running .exe from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152482/running-exe-from-javascript), but I am trying to handle input to the executable, and thus will need to be able to interact with the user from JavaScript and then feed that input into the executable. Thus, I need to be able to "pause" the running of the executable while I wait for input to give it from the user. Is this possible?

EDIT:: I will be running this from a JavaScript server

Comment: Depends on the environment. If you're planning on running it in a browser then the answer is no, although you may be able to compile your original program using [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) to make it work. If you plan to run this on the server-side using Node.js then it's possible.

Comment: What environment/os/host are you running the JavaScript inside?

Comment: I will be running this from a JavaScript server using nodeJS @AlexK.

Comment: Seems a DLL rather than an EXE would be a better choice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364047/nodejshow-to-call-c-dll-function-through-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this from a browser but if you use [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/) you will be able to achieve what you want with this lines of code

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('path/to/exe', function(error, stdout, stderr, callback) {
        //do something here
});
```

Comment: That won't work. OP wants to be able to feed input while the program is running. `exec` will run the program to completion then give you the output.

Comment: I thought @Elias Marcopoulos wanted that, give an `input` to the `exe` and get an `output` from the exe right?

Comment: "need to be able to interact with the user from JavaScript and then feed that input into the executable. Thus, I need to be able to "pause" the running of the executable while I wait for input to give it from the user"

Comment: It is actually possible to run executables in a browser, since there are several [x86 emulators in JavaScript](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25162/x86-emulator-in-javascript-to-run-linux-windows-or-dos) that can run native binaries.