# Use Methods from dll file in js file

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, dll, electron

I have old dll files that I was using in old windows Forms application and I need to include them in my new project and I need to access these files/methods from javascript.
my target is to make a web application and and then transfer it to desktop app using electron.js

Any Recommendations?

I have tried ActiveXObject but is it not supported in chrome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodejs:How to call c++ DLL function through nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364047/nodejshow-to-call-c-dll-function-through-nodejs)

Comment: thanks Mr. @AlexanderLeithner,. this will not create problems we i convert it to electron?