# Call C code from node.js

Tags: c++, c, node.js

Let's say i have source and header files for C code (*bus-driver.c* and *bus-driver.h*) **can i call functions inside them from node.js**

for example *bus-driver.h*

```
void bus_init(void);
void bus_write(char *buf);
```

I want to call these functions from node.js.

Comment: Maybe a duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629677/how-can-i-use-a-c-library-from-node-js

Comment: Or look at: https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

Comment: I read them, but i don't understand them. if you could give me example with bus-driver.h it could be very helpful, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nodeffi seems to be simplest way to do that.
I didn't test it so it can has problems that I don't realize now.

But I would suggest to do something like that, following the [tutorial](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/wiki/Node-FFI-Tutorial).
Install [nodeffi](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi):

Generate a library for your bus-driver if you don't have one, let's call it libbusdriver.

Then in your javascript do something similar to this:

```
var ffi = require('ffi');

var libbusdriver = ffi.Library('libbusdriver', {
  'bus_init': [ 'void', [ 'void' ] ],
  'bus_write': [ 'void', [ 'string' ] ],
});
libbusdriver.bus_init();
libbusdriver.bus_write("Hello");
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I tried it, and have this error after executing node.js program **Error: Dynamic Linking Error: libusbdriver.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory** the library and test.js file is in the same directory, i tried to rename library .so and .a with no difference

Comment: Are you naming it libusbdriver or libbusdriver?

Comment: sorry i change it to libbusdriver but get the same error. is it true to place node.js program and the library in the same directory?

Comment: Did you generate the library with shared flag on?

Comment: I used **gcc -c libbusdriver.c -o libbusdriver.o** to compile and **ar  rcs libbusdriver libbusdriver.o** to generate the library

Comment: Try using gcc -shared: gcc -shared -o libbusdriver.so libbusdriver.o

Comment: i get this error when creating the library **/usr/bin/ld: libbusdriver.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
libbusdriver.o: error adding symbols: Bad value**

Comment: Follow the instructions and recompile with -fPIC before generate the shared library

Comment: I found the error, `
var libbusdriver = ffi.Library('./libbusdriver', { ...` we should spicify the directory so i added ./ and it worked. very thanks to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87894/discussion-between-danielfranca-and-nasr).