# calling c++ function from node.js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, dll, cloud

i'm trying to develop module on cloud (c++ DLL executable)
i need to let to a client (web page) that develop in node.js to use this DLL functions.

i'am trying build a small program that call to c++ DLL function from node.js native  ,

any hint how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use a C++ library from node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629677/how-can-i-use-a-c-library-from-node-js)

Comment: UPDATE: i have already console application that know to communicate with alarm system (through mediator server), i want to implement my console app to be a dll (and not a "live" process on the air) and this dll expose functions to the client, (web page that develop with node.js ),  any hints?