# Is it possible to invoke Node.js libraries in Win32 application or vice versa?

Tags: node.js, winapi

Node.js applications and Win32 binaries are two different worlds.

I am wondering if there are ways to access any Node.js libraries or functions directly from a Win32 process (in-process invocation)?

This following question shall work by refering to [How can I use a C++ library from node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629677/how-can-i-use-a-c-library-from-node-js)

> Similarly, is it possible for Node.js application to invoke functions
>   exported from Windows DLLs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use a C++ library from node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629677/how-can-i-use-a-c-library-from-node-js)

Comment: The other way around, you'll have to have a way to host a Node runtime from an arbitrary runtime on an arbitrary platform and marshalling arbitrary variable types, I don't know whether that exists. Maybe through [Owin](https://tomasz.janczuk.org/2013/02/hosting-net-code-in-nodejs-applications.html).

Comment: You can write a Windows Store application using JavaScript, and make native system calls available through Windows Runtime components (see [Walkthrough: Creating a basic Windows Runtime component in C++ and calling it from JavaScript or C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/walkthrough-creating-a-basic-windows-runtime-component-in-cpp-and-calling-it-from-javascript-or-csharp)). For a Windows Desktop application you will have to host the JavaScript runtime environment yourself.