# Node JS with C++ integration

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, swig, node-gyp

I'm new to Node JS, just setting up the environment for integrating Node JS with C++.
I'm trying the example mentioned in this [Node JS - C++ Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629677/how-can-i-use-a-c-library-from-node-js) provided by enobayram using SWIG.
However when I'm trying to use node-gyp build it is throwing up lots of error.

My environment

OS: Windows 7 Professional x64
Python: 2.7.11
Node: v4.4.1
Node-Gyp: v3.3.1
MS VS: MS Visual Studio Community 2015

```
D:\Example>node-gyp build
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.3.1
gyp info using node@4.4.1 | win32 | x64
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  mylib_wrap.cxx
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(614): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint16_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
  c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(642): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'v8::PersistentBase<T>' being compiled
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(620): error C3646: 'WrapperClassId': unknown override specifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(620): error C2059: syntax error: ')' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(620): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(1149): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(1149): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '*' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(1154): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(1154): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(1154): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(1228): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(1228): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '*' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(1384): error C3646: 'CachedDataVersionTag': unknown override specifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(1384): error C2059: syntax error: ')' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(1384): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(1143): error C2789: 'v8::ScriptCompiler::CachedData::uint8_t': an object of const-qualified type must be initialized [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
  c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(1154): note: see declaration of 'v8::ScriptCompiler::CachedData::uint8_t'
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(1143): error C2614: 'v8::ScriptCompiler::CachedData': illegal member initialization: 'data' is not a base or member [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(1536): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2003): error C2065: 'int64_t': undeclared identifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2003): error C2923: 'v8::Maybe': 'int64_t' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2005): error C2065: 'uint32_t': undeclared identifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2005): error C2923: 'v8::Maybe': 'uint32_t' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2007): error C2065: 'int32_t': undeclared identifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2007): error C2923: 'v8::Maybe': 'int32_t' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2011): error C3646: 'IntegerValue': unknown override specifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2011): error C2059: syntax error: '(' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2011): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2012): error C3646: 'Uint32Value': unknown override specifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2012): error C2059: syntax error: '(' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2012): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2013): error C3646: 'Int32Value': unknown override specifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2013): error C2059: syntax error: '(' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2013): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2151): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint16_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2156): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint8_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2222): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2222): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2222): error C2433: 'v8::String::ExternalStringResource::uint16_t': 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2222): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2305): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2301): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '*' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2310): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2310): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '*' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2311): error C2556: 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::String> v8::String::NewFromOneByte(v8::Isolate *,const int)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'v8::Local<v8::String> v8::String::NewFromOneByte(v8::Isolate *,const int)' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
  c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2305): note: see declaration of 'v8::String::NewFromOneByte'
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2311): error C2371: 'v8::String::NewFromOneByte': redefinition; different basic types [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
  c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2305): note: see declaration of 'v8::String::NewFromOneByte'
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2318): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2314): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '*' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2323): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2323): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '*' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2324): error C2556: 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::String> v8::String::NewFromTwoByte(v8::Isolate *,const int)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'v8::Local<v8::String> v8::String::NewFromTwoByte(v8::Isolate *,const int)' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
  c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2318): note: see declaration of 'v8::String::NewFromTwoByte'
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2324): error C2371: 'v8::String::NewFromTwoByte': redefinition; different basic types [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
  c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2318): note: see declaration of 'v8::String::NewFromTwoByte'
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2422): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2422): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2422): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2423): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2423): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2423): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2426): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2426): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2426): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2230): error C2789: 'v8::String::ExternalStringResource::uint16_t': an object of const-qualified type must be initialized [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
  c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2222): note: see declaration of 'v8::String::ExternalStringResource::uint16_t'
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2499): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'int32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2500): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2501): error C3646: 'Value': unknown override specifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2501): error C2059: syntax error: '(' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2501): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2514): error C3646: 'Value': unknown override specifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2514): error C2059: syntax error: '(' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2514): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2528): error C3646: 'Value': unknown override specifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2528): error C2059: syntax error: '(' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2528): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2595): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2596): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2610): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2643): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2645): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2673): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2674): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2676): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2678): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2808): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2810): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2950): error C3646: 'Length': unknown override specifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2950): error C2059: syntax error: '(' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2950): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2957): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(2959): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(3075): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'int32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
  c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(3098): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'v8::ReturnValue<T>' being compiled
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(3076): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(3076): error C2535: 'void v8::ReturnValue<T>::Set(void)': member function already defined or declared [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
  c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(3075): note: see declaration of 'v8::ReturnValue<T>::Set'
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4178): error C2065: 'uint32_t': undeclared identifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4178): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'index' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4187): error C2065: 'uint32_t': undeclared identifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4187): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'index' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4197): error C2065: 'uint32_t': undeclared identifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4197): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'index' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4207): error C2065: 'uint32_t': undeclared identifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4207): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'index' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4246): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4477): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'IndexedPropertyGetterCallback' [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4494): error C3646: 'getter': unknown override specifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4494): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4495): error C3646: 'setter': unknown override specifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4495): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4496): error C3646: 'query': unknown override specifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4496): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4497): error C3646: 'deleter': unknown override specifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4497): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4477): error C2065: 'getter': undeclared identifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4487): error C2065: 'setter': undeclared identifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4488): error C2065: 'query': undeclared identifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4489): error C2065: 'deleter': undeclared identifier [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4492): error C2614: 'v8::IndexedPropertyHandlerConfiguration': illegal member initialization: 'getter' is not a base or member [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4492): error C2614: 'v8::IndexedPropertyHandlerConfiguration': illegal member initialization: 'setter' is not a base or member [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4492): error C2614: 'v8::IndexedPropertyHandlerConfiguration': illegal member initialization: 'query' is not a base or member [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4492): error C2614: 'v8::IndexedPropertyHandlerConfiguration': illegal member initialization: 'deleter' is not a base or member [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
c:\users\rtv\.node-gyp\4.4.1\include\node\v8.h(4492): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation [D:\Example\build\mylib.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\rtv\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\rtv\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Example
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok

D:\Example>
```

Request your help to resolve this issue.

FYI, I've tried installing different version of MS VS, still similar issue exists.

Comment: Thanks @Keith for correcting CPP to C++.

Comment: Update::: Since I'm stuck here, I tried to do it in Linux. So installed ubuntu 14.04 in Virtual Box. Now I'm able to configure & build in linux using node-gyp, however when using the file in node it says module is not self registered.

Comment: This is probably not the answer you're looking for but at times instead of wrestling with plumbing for connecting between languages I just opt for setting up a simple TCP protocol or using zeromq or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first go at C++ & Node.js integration, you might find it easiest to start at the [Node.js C/C++ Addons documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/addons.html#addons_addon_examples).

The very first "Hello Word" example is a great one to get familiar with Node's C++ requirements.

The process of integrating Node.js & C++ can be tricky at the best of times. The implementation has changed across versions of Node.js and you'll find plenty of examples on the net which don't work with the current version of Node.