# ccTalk Library Nodejs/Javascript / Use a C# Library in Nodejs

Tags: c#, node.js, wrapper, cctalk

I'm searching for a ccTalk library for nodejs. I only found an [abandoned one](https://github.com/askbeka/node-ccTalk).

An alternative might be to use a non javascript library like this one and compile it for nodejs
https://code.google.com/archive/p/cctalk-net/

I found this for usage non js code in nodejs but I have 0 experience with converting it.

[How can I use a C++ library from node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629677/how-can-i-use-a-c-library-from-node-js#answer-27917698)
http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html

https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge

## Questions

1) Is there a library for node.js

2) How to include the above library into my nodejs app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can compile custom dll using VS from https://github.com/Hitman666/nbCcTalkCoinAcceptor
2. Install edge from https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge
   or simple **npm install edge**
3. Create **sample.js** file with something like:

   coinAcc = edge.func({
       source: function () {/*
           //your c# code (see Hitmans nbCcTalkCoinAcceptor_exe for example)
       */},
       references: ['yourcctallib.dll']
   });

//define port and it should pool...

4. Suggestion: Develop some kind of messaging from c# directly to node (socket like dgram or similar) and pass all events to some port, from node listen realtime cctalk device, because after successful config of cctalk device you basically only need to read from it(pool).