# How to run a c++ executable file when using javascript for updating firebase realtime database?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase realtime database in which there is already some data stored. I want to read the data on firebase and execute some query by using some already implemeted datastructure. Problem is, the library i will be using is in c++. But i can read and update firebase only through javascript(using node.js). So, i was thinking to write code in c++, make a executable file and run that through javascript. But I don't know if it is really possible and if it is then how will the executable file get uploaded along with node.js file? Any kind of hint will be helpful.

Comment: Read about [extending `node.js` with native C++ modules](https://medium.com/@marcinbaraniecki/extending-node-js-with-native-c-modules-63294a91ce4)

Comment: near duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9629677/841108) question