# js koffi - call dll from js

Tags: javascript, dll

I should call a DLL (Win x64) function from JS code.

Definitions in C:

```
typedef void*  HNDL;
ABCD_DLL_DECL DWORD WINAPI  ABCD_Create(HNDL* pHNDL);
```

So the HNDL is a pointer and the create function will give back an object pointer (pHNDL).

I have tried to use these in JS:

```
const Handle = koffi.pointer("Handle", koffi.opaque());
const ABCD_Create = lib.func("uint __stdcall ABCD_Create(_Inout_ Handle *pHandle)";

let hHandle;
let err = ABCD_Create(hHandle);
```

or

```
const ABCD_Create = lib.func("uint __stdcall ABCD_Create(_Inout_ void *phandle)";
```

or

```
const Handle = koffi.opaque();
const ABCD_Create = lib.func("ABCD_Create", "uint", [koffi.out(koffi.pointer(Handle, 2))]);
```

I have tried a lot of combination of these and other samples in examples from documentation of koffi, but when I call the create function I always get the "Process exited with code 3221225477" in VSCode. (The original code works perfectly in VC and Delphi...)  This error number is the 0xC0000005. It means access violation. So I think somewhere the parameter passing is wrong.

How should I define it and call the create function correctly (with koffi)?

Comment: it's nodeJS or browser?

Comment: see this http://bmbgk.ir/?q=nodeJS+c%2B%2B+extention and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629677/how-can-i-use-a-c-library-from-node-js

Comment: Yes, it is in nodeJS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a similar example in koffi tests (sqlite.js). So the following declaration works:

```
const Handle = koffi.opaque("Handle");
const ABCD_Create = lib.func("ABCD_Create","uint", koffi.out(koffi.pointer(Handle, 2))]";
```

... and the calling:

```
let phandle = [null];
let handle = null;

const err = ABCD_Create(phandle);
if (err != 0) {
  console.error(`Create failed. Error = ${err}`);
  return;
}

handle = phandle[0];
```