# Is there a tool that can convert a Visual Studio object file to GCC format?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, cross-compiling, interix

I am building a C++ application on Windows using Interix and need to link in three object files to supply a third-party licensing module's functionality.  The third party has supplied the object files as built by Visual Studio.  Is there anyway to convert the files for use with GCC?  For example, perhaps if I change the name mangling from Visual Studio style to GCC style that would be sufficient, or are there other differences between the two object file formats?

Comment: This is a very hard thing to do.

Comment: There are lots of differences other than just name mangling. Better forget it, you will have much more chances asking the third party either for the code so you can compile it yourself, or for GCC (MinGW?) object files. Don't forget to explicitly state your GCC/MinGW version to ensure ABI compatibility.

Comment: Easiest solution would be to get Visual C++ Express Edition, and wrap the object files in a DLL with C interface. GCC on Windows understands that; the OS is provided as DLL's with a C interface after all.

Comment: @MSalters Sounds like you have the makings of an answer there!  Would you please elaborate on the details and add an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows does not have a standardized C++ ABI (Application *Binary* Interface). It does have a C ABI, though. This is the ABI used for instance by `Kernel32.DLL`, so all Windows programming environments understand it. Many can also produce such DLLs.

In this case, the C++ .obj files have to be linked by the Visual Studio linker. That linker is definitely capable of creating DLL files. You'll have to write `extern "C"` functions to wrap the licensing functionality. Add `__declspec(dllexport)` to indicate that those functions are exported from the DLL (on Windows, functions by default are private to a DLL).

In a header, declare those same functions as `__declspec(dllimport)`. GCC understands that as well. Then link against the newly produced DLL, which will resolve the `dllimport`'ed symbols.

Comment: If you go down this path you may find some of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045774/developing-c-wrapper-api-for-object-oriented-c-code helpful (disclaimer - accepted answer is mine...)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the possible symbol differences between VC++ and GCC/G++, what's you are trying to do may be impossible due to Windows API issue.

Programs that built from Interix GCC can only work with Interix, and since Interix is a separated subsystem in parallel of the Windows subsystem (or say Win32 subsystem), you can't call any Windows API (ex. from kernel32.dll) from Interix programs.

If that licensing object file contain any Windows API calls, linking will not be possible.