# Build DLL (MyMathFuncs) for use in Python Ctypes

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

As a complete novice with C++ I just created my first Dynamic Link Library following the MS tutorial found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

The header file reads as follows:

```
// MathFuncsDll.h

namespace MathFuncs
{
    class MyMathFuncs
    {
    public:
        // Returns a + b
        static __declspec(dllexport) double Add(double a, double b);

        // Returns a - b
        static __declspec(dllexport) double Subtract(double a, double b);

        // Returns a * b
        static __declspec(dllexport) double Multiply(double a, double b);

        // Returns a / b
        // Throws DivideByZeroException if b is 0
        static __declspec(dllexport) double Divide(double a, double b);
    };
}
```

Now, I want to read this file into Python ctypes.  I do this using:

```
import ctypes as ctypes

MyDll = 'MathFuncsDll.dll'
MyFuncs = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(MyDll)
```

Now, I'm struggling to actually access the functions.   My intuition leads me to try

```
a = ctypes.c_double(54)
b = ctypes.c_double(12)

summation = MyFuncs.Add(a,b)
```

which returns the error

```
AttributeError: function 'Add' not found
```

Is my problem that the function is nested within the `class MyMathFuncs` which is also within `namespace MathFuncs`?  How do I gain access to these functions?

For reference, below is the contents of the `.cpp` file used to generate the dll

```
// MathFuncsDll.cpp
// compile with: /EHsc /LD

#include "MathFuncsDll.h"

#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

namespace MathFuncs
{
    double MyMathFuncs::Add(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Subtract(double a, double b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Multiply(double a, double b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Divide(double a, double b)
    {
        if (b == 0)
        {
            throw new invalid_argument("b cannot be zero!");
        }

        return a / b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access C++ classes and namespaces using the `ctypes`. There is no standard binary interface for C++, as there is for C. Every compiler outputs it's own (different) binaries for the same C++ dynamic libraries. You can read more about it [here](http://blog.vrplumber.com/b/2007/07/21/ctypes-for-c-is).

The thing you **can** do (if you have to do it in C++) is do all your work in C++ and then write a tiny layer of C that wraps it and exposes it. Then you'll be able to access it using `ctypes`. Again, you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045774/developing-c-wrapper-api-for-object-oriented-c-code)

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks.  Do you know if there is a straightforward way to make a "C" DLL as opposed to a "C++" DLL?  What is inherently C++ about this DLL (other than using a C++ compiler, of course).

Comment: Not sure what is your question exactly? You can make a C DLL compiling C code with a C compiler or exposing C++ code using `extern "C" {`. DLL's have their binary interface, but different C++ compilers, unfortunately, output different binaries for the same C++ code, due to name handling and/or different ways to manage the stack between library function calls.

Comment: Hmm... so what exactly would you enclose in the extern C brackets?  Do you need to do make similar adjustments for both the cpp and the header file?

Comment: This is a bit offtopic. And it's explained in a lot of places on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045774/developing-c-wrapper-api-for-object-oriented-c-code) and [many](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/thesolution.html) [other](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/) [places](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B)...