# Create a C wrapper around a C++ library that can be linked by a C linker

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, static-libraries

Following the answer given to [this question (Developing C wrapper API for Object-Oriented C++ code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045774/developing-c-wrapper-api-for-object-oriented-c-code) I managed to write a C wrapper for my C++ code.

I would like to compile and link my wrapper into a static library (compiled using g++) that could be used, compiled and linked using gcc only (not g++). This way the user of the library would not have to care that the library is written in C++.

Is this something possible?

Comment: Following link explains a bit: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-3690/Building.Libs.html

Scroll down to 16.7 for compiler options which I think apply to your situation

Comment: @NeilNeyman This answer my question indeed. Unfortunately it confirms the client application of my library needs to be linked with stdc++. But it's seems that's the only way to go. If you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link explains some of the compiler options and scenarios: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-3690/Building.Libs.html   Specifically:

[>  16.7    Building a Library That Has a C API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-3690/Building.Libs.html#marker-10071)

> > If you want to build a library that is written in C++ but that can be
> >     used with a C program, you must create a C API (application
> >     programming interface). To do this, make all the exported functions
> >     extern "C". Note that this can be done only for global functions and
> >     not for member functions.
> >
> > If a C-interface library needs C++ run-time support and you are
> >     linking with cc, then you must also link your application with either
> >     libC (compatibility mode) or libCrun (standard mode) when you use the
> >     C-interface library. (If the C-interface library does not need C++
> >     run-time support, then you do not have to link with libC or libCrun.)
> >     The steps for linking differ for archived and shared libraries.
> >
> > When providing an archived C-interface library, you must provide
> >     instructions on how to use the library.
> >
> > If the C-interface library was built with CC in standard mode (the
> >     default), add -lCrun to the cc command line when using the C-interface
> >     library. If the C-interface library was built with CC in compatibility
> >     mode (-compat), add -lC to the cc command line when using the
> >     C-interface library. When providing a shared C-interface library you
> >     must create a dependency on libC or libCrun at the time that you build
> >     the library. When the shared library has the correct dependency, you
> >     do not need to add -lC or -lCrun to the command line when you use the
> >     library.
> >
> > If you are building the C-interface library in compatibility mode
> >     (-compat), add -lC to the CC command line when you build the library.
> >     If you are building the C-interface library in standard mode (the
> >     default), add -lCrun to the CC command line when you build the
> >     library. If you want to remove any dependency on the C++ runtime
> >     libraries, you should enforce the following coding rules in your
> >     library sources:
> >
> > Do not use any form of new or delete unless you provide your own
> >     corresponding versions. Do not use exceptions. Do not use runtime type
> >     information (RTTI).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to provide the C interface with functions that have C linkage. Exactly as the linked question's answer work although for the header you will need to make it C-compliant. The common way would be using an `#ifdef __cplusplus` to detect whether the compiler is a C or C++ compiler.

```
// MyHeader
#ifndef MYHEADER
#define MYHEADER
#ifdef __cplusplus
// Class definition or any other C++ code
extern "C" {
#endif
// C only code here
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I did. Then using g++ and ar I compiled this to wrapper.a. When I write a C application and try to link it with wrapper.a it has some undefined references (to things like std::string stuff for example). If I use g++ (which I want to avoid) it works.

Comment: @MathieuPagé: Well, you will have to link all the object files you need, and probably the C++ library, either statically or dynamically

Comment: Link C++ library statically, if you want to avoid having the client application have to provide `std::string` or the like