# How to compile a C app linking a C-wrapper library containing C++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have a static library with C++ internals but with a C wrapper so that C code can call the library.

- Using g++, no issue.
- Using gcc, I get lots of `undefined reference to` at the library's internal functions.
- The C code calls only the C functions in the C wrapper.
- The problem is from internal calls inside the library not to the "API".

The C wrapper contains:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

Why? Can we link a **static** library containing C++ but exposing only C functions to a C application?

What's the point of writing a C wrapper for a C++ library if we still need to compile the C code as C++?

Comment: It's not so much a matter of C vs C++ as it is about dependencies. The library is written in C++, and sounds like it uses the C++ runtime. g++ links it implicitly, which is why it "just works".

Comment: Please show a [mre] including the full error messages

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica But why? The library is already compiled. The C app communicates with the library only via C calls. The linker shouldn't care what the library actually contains internally, what matters is what the C app calls. No?

Comment: The duplicate is far too broad to be helpful. Voting to re-open.

Comment: @Alexis No need to edit your question if it gets closed, that's just confusing. Instead explain in comments why it isn't a duplicate. I've gold badger re-opened the question now, you can remove those edits.

Comment: Thank you @Lundin, it's removed. In the meantime I found the solution that worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195932/create-a-c-wrapper-around-a-c-library-that-can-be-linked-by-a-c-linker I'll delete the question in few minutes since it's still a duplicate.

Comment: No need to delete the question but we can pick that one you found as target instead.

Comment: *"The linker shouldn't care what the library actually contains internally"* - For an archived library, it very much does care. A library for static linking is essentially just a bunch of object files wrapped in an archive. Whatever those objects call need to be brought in for the linker to resolve. The C++ runtime is just one case of that. You'd hit the same problem if you depend on 3rd-party library code too.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica It makes sense but it just defeats the purpose of writing a C-wrapper... I hope it doesn't create issues with `cgo` or `rust`.