# Vuforia: getting namespace error while using in Swift Xcode Project

Tags: swift, vuforia

I am trying to use Vuforia static library into a Swift xcode project, but getting unknown type error for c++ namespaces,

**error: Unknown type name 'namespace' in the Matrices.h file**

Comment: You *cannot* import C++ code into Swift: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229149/interacting-with-c-classes-from-swift.

Comment: Thanks Martin, but when I went through this github code its working there, Let me know if you have any ideas.
https://github.com/yshrkt/VuforiaSampleSwift

Comment: You'll have to post the relevant code, and show exactly where the error message occurs.