# swift compiler not able to find c++ libraries

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c++

I created two single view iOS projects from Xcode. The first one in Swift and the second one in Objective-C.

In those two projects, I add both Test.cpp / Test.hpp files which only include  C++ library. Of course, for the Swift project only, I have to create a Bridging Header to import this file.

Test.hpp file looks like this:

```
#ifndef TestCpp_hpp
#define TestCpp_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

#endif /* TestCpp_hpp */
```

The issue I have is that the Objective-C project is building successfully, meanwhile the Swift project fails to find the `cstdlib` C++ library.

I checked the compilation command and the Swift project uses `swift` to build. The Objective-C project uses `clang`.

I tried to change the `C++ Language Dialect` and `C++ Standard Library` in the build settings but nothing is working.

Is there some special setup to do in order to be able to build the Swift project?

Comment: Could you please paste the xcode build error snapshot here? which xcode version you are using? Do you have any code in Test.cpp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot include C++ headers in your bridging header to call C++ code directly from Swift.  Essentially, there are at least two options.

- Write a C wrapper around C++ code and incorporate the C wrapper into
  Swift via the bridging header.
- Write an Objective-C++ wrapper with an API that does not involve C++
  types.  Internally the wrapper implementation can call C++ code.  Invoke your wrapper API in Swift like you would invoke any Objective-C code.

Both of these approaches are described here:

[Interacting with C++ classes from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229149/interacting-with-c-classes-from-swift)