# Form C header file "'vector' file not found" error happening into swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, c-header

I am trying to integrate an Objective-C SDK into my swift file. But when I want to add some of the files from the SDK into my **Bridging Header** I am getting this error **'vector' file not found**

I am also getting **string file not found** if I want to add other file to the swift header.

I discover these are the C header file. SDK provider gave some hint like create a **.mm** file, but how they don't know.

I have tried adding all the C or C++ supporting files like **libstdc++.6.tbd,libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd, libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib, libstdc++.6.dylib, libstdc++.dylib** but nothings changed.

Here is the error
https://pasteboard.co/InhuW5K.png

And here is the **Bridging Header** file integration

```
#ifndef IOT_Demo_Bridging_Header_h
#define IOT_Demo_Bridging_Header_h //#ifndef ObjectiveCHeader_h //#define ObjectiveCHeader_h

#import <LCOpenSDKDynamic/LCOpenSDK_Api.h> //#import "../Depend/LCOpenSDK/LCOpenSDK_Api.h"
#import <LCOpenSDKDynamic/LCOpenSDK_AudioTalk.h>
#import <LCOpenSDKDynamic/LCOpenSDK_PlayWindow.h>
#import <LCOpenSDKDynamic/LCOpenSDK_EventListener.h>
#import <LCOpenSDKDynamic/LCOpenSDK_TalkerListener.h>
#import <LCOpenSDKDynamic/DeviceList.h>
#endif
```

I am stuck with is this error for some days. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there no solution at all??

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running into problems trying to use C++ code in Swift.  See, for example, this answer: [Interacting with C++ classes from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229149/interacting-with-c-classes-from-swift). `vector` and `string` are standard C++ library headers.

Also, doing searches like `use c++ in swift`, `call c++ from swift`, etc. in Google and StackOverflow should provide enough examples of how to handle this.

Briefly, one approach is to write an Objective-C++ wrapper.  Implementation files, with the `.mm` extension, will be a mixture of Objective-C and C++ code, i.e. C++ API can be invoked by code in those files.  However, the functions that are to be made visible to Swift via the bridging header should not use C++ types as parameters or return values.

Comment: I am using an Objective C framework, inside that there is C header file. So how can I change the framework file? Any example will be helpful.