# How can I wrap a static library (C++) into an XCFramework for use in Swift?

Tags: c++, swift, xcode, static-linking, xcframework

I have been given a static library `libExample.a` together with a bunch of C++ headers, which I need to use in an iOS app. The binary is fat, containing objects for iphoneos-arm64/e and iphonesimulator-x64.

I have done some research on the subject and came to the conclusion, that using a XCFramework would be the best thing to do. Still, I feel completely out of my depth, since this is my first time trying anything of the sort.

### What I have done so far

#### 1. Creating the XCFramework from library files

1. `lipo -extract` architectures from fat binary
2. `xcodebuild -create-xcframework -library LIB-arm64.a -headers HEADERS -library ...`

Importing the XCFramework into my Swift project didn't yield any usable modules. Also the folder was missing a lot of the files, I've seen in examples. It seemed like the wrong way to go about it, so I tried...

#### 2. Creating a Framework and then a XCFramework from it

###### Files

1. Create new Objective-C Framework project `ExampleFramework`
2. Pull all my headers and the fat binary into the project
3. Add all my headers to the `ExampleFramework.h` umbrella header
4. Create the following `ExampleFramework.modulemap`:

```
framework module ExampleFramework {
    umbrella header "ExampleFramework.h”
    
    link "Example"
    export *
    module * { export * }
}
```

###### Settings

1. **General**:
   1.1. Add `libExample.a` to *Frameworks & Libraries*
2. **Build Phases**:
   2.1. Make all headers public
   2.2. Add `libExample.a` to *Link Binary with Libraries*
   2.3. Add `libExample.a` to *Copy Bundle Resources*
3. **Build Settings**:
   3.1. *Skip Install* : `No`
   3.2. *Build Libraries for distribution* : `Yes`
   3.3. *Module map file*: `ExampleFramework/ExampleFramework.modulemap`
   3.4. *Defines modules*: `Yes`
   3.5. *Compile Sources As*: `Objective-C++`

I then archived the framework, for `iphoneos` and `iphonesimulator` respectively:

```
xcodebuild archive \
-scheme "ExampleFramework" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
-archivePath "path/to/ExampleFramework_${SDK}.xcarchive" \
-sdk ${SDK} \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```

...and generated a XCFramework from the outputs:

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
-framework "path/to/ExampleFramework_iphoneos.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/ExampleFramework.framework"
-framework ...
-output "path/to/ExampleFramework.xcframework"
```

### Build Errors

The folder structure I got from this looked promising, so I tried adding the XCFramework to my iOS project. The module was being found now, but XCode stopped compiling at the first #include, saying it wasn't able to find `stdexcept`, from which I concluded it was missing the C++ standard library headers.

I tried setting *Header Search Paths* in **Build Settings**. Looking for the right path I found a couple, that looked relevant to me:

```
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include
/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include
```

Depending on which one I choose and whether I clean before building, I'm getting a bunch of different errors (it seems random). Mainly:

`Unknown type name 'namespace'`

and lots and lots of others, that lead to me believe XCode doesn't recognize the headers as C++.

Or:

`Cyclic dependency on module 'Darwin' : Darwin -> std -> Darwin`

I really have no idea at this point, so any solutions or suggestions pointing me into the right direction, would me **much** appreciated. I'd also be open to some completely different approach, I just want to use the library somehow.

**Thanks!**

Comment: You can't directly call C++ code from Swift. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229149/interacting-with-c-classes-from-swift) Q&A for how to do that. This has nothing to do with xcframeworks.

Answer (score 0):

For reference from module.modulemap

```
framework module GoogleAppMeasurement {
umbrella header "GoogleAppMeasurement-umbrella.h"
export *
module * { export * }
  link framework "Security"
  link framework "SystemConfiguration"
  link "c++"
  link "sqlite3"
  link "z"
}
```