# Tetgen in C Language

Tags: c++, c, mixing, tetgen

I am currently using Tetgen to generate Delaunay triangulation, but since I have to use C programming language and not C++, is there a way in which I can call Tetgen from C?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well, you can wrap c++ API's with plain c API's but that's a very broad topic and may not get a concise answer here.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045774/developing-c-wrapper-api-for-object-oriented-c-code) Q&A can help you get started.

Comment: In order to call tergen, you will have to write *some* C++ code. Why do you have to use C?

Comment: The library will form part of a bigger code,  which is in C, so I am 'obliged' to use C...  Will the Api interface modify the original library?

Comment: Having some part of your project in C does not preclude you from writing other parts in C++. If it's OK to use C++ code written by somebody else (Tetgen), it should be OK to use C++ code written by yourself.