# Finding the coresponding Type in C

Tags: c++, c

I would like to translate a C++ code in C. I have some C++ types I don't know the corresponding type in C.

C++ types: `std::vector<std::string>` and `map<std::string, std::string>`.

I thank you in advance.

```
ReturnCode CSVReader::GetConstValue(const char * material_code, const char * product_category, const char * material_name, const char * material_number, DataColumns ret_column, std::string & return_val)
{
    std::map<DataColumns, std::string> where_col;
    GetFixedColumns(where_col, material_code ? material_code : "", product_category ? product_category: "", material_name ? material_name : "", material_number ? material_number : "");
    return FindField(where_col, ret_column, return_val);
}
```

Comment: C only supports primitive data types as standard.

Comment: std::map<std::string, std::string>

Comment: You will have to come up with your own implementation.

Comment: There is no corresponding type in C. Depending on your C++ code (which we don't see) translating it to C may be very hard. Show at least some of your code.

Comment: Don't translate; *interop* instead. C++ can be compiled to have C style linkage although of course you can't share C++ objects at interface boundaries.

Comment: Don't put code in comments, it's unreadable. Instead [edit] your question.

Comment: It would be much easier and safer to create a c wrapper to your code and create a library to link to it, than rewriting this.

Comment: I thank you Jabberwocky. I don't know yet how to use Stackoverflow.

Comment: @jultaps invest some time in learning it (less than 15 minutes should be enough), you'll see it's pretty easy.

Comment: Your question really needs more context than just the code you gave. Where do `GetFixedColumns` and `FindField` come from? Do you want to rewrite them, too? If not, you must provide the types that the function asks for.

Comment: @MOehm I wanted to know if there were corresponding types of the types I gave, in C. Because I didn't want to put some effort and energy creating structs and functions. Now I have to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Some approaches here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045774/developing-c-wrapper-api-for-object-oriented-c-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ types are build up by primitives that could be used in C also, but some of the language specific stuff, like destructors, must be syntesized.

A std::vector is basically a struct, some defines and some functions

```
struct vector {
  size_type size;
  size_type capacity;
  int *data;
};
```

Then you have the problem of templates, but those are basically macro's with type checks, the latter could be a problem.

```
#define vector(type) \
struct vector##type { \
  size_type size; \
  size_type capacity; \
  type *data; \
};
```

Then you will have to add any special c'tor, all the member functions, which will have to be function pointers I think.

That would be too much work I think, so you can just use the original struct and work your way through what you need for the specific type.

Map can be emulated by a struct vector and using binary search on it, you don't want to implement a red-black tree. You could also use a hash map if you can find one in C.

Comment: Yes, this will work for the simplest scenarios, but emulating destructors or move/copy semantics will be much harder.

Comment: @Groo which is why C++ makes my life much easier that doing all the extra stuff and having to remember all the boring stuff.