# To add c++ header files in C header using C compiler?

Tags: c++, c, header

I have a C++ header file, which I am including in a project running with a C compiler. and I have a few errors in the C++ header file since the syntaxes are different for both the compilers, obviously. But the hurdle is I should not modify the c++ header file. I tried using 'C' extern after reading from a few posts but seems the C compiler is not recognizing "__cplusplus".

is there any way that can be implemented in a C header file to include a C++ header file??

for eg.  the C compiler is giving an error "Identifier 'Current' is undefined", because there is a 'struct' keyword missing in front of 'Current' in below code.

```
struct Current {
    uint16_t mini; 
    uint16_t maxi; 
    uint16_t counter; 
};  
struct someConstraint { 
    union { 
        Current ac_curr; 
    };
};
```

Please help and thank you !!

VP

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish for your C program, by including the C++ header file, in the first place? C++ is a completely different language from C. No C compiler will make any sense of C++ class declarations, or any C++ specific grammar.

Comment: I am working with a C compiler, but there is a dependency on the header file which is compiled well in C++ and I have no choice but to include it. 
to give an example: struct Current {
    uint16_t    min;
    uint16_t    max;
    uint16_t    ctr;
};

struct someConstraint {
    uint8_t     type;
    union {
      Current ac_current;
    };
};     the C compiler is giving an error "Identifier 'Current' is undefined", because there is a 'struct' keyword missing in front of 'Current'.

Comment: A C header file can include a C++ header file if the C++ header file has taken steps to be C compatible.  If you cannot modify the C++ header file, and the C++ header file is not C compatible, then you can't use it.  At best, you can write a separate header file that is C compatible that is the subset of the C++ header file that needs to be shared with C.  (Those identifiers still need to be C naming friendly, and not C++ mangled.)

Comment: Please post (a) some of the errors and (b) the parts of the C++ header file giving the errors posted in (a).  Please read [ask] with a [mcve].

Comment: You have to write a C header. And use `#ifdef __cplusplus   extern "C" { #endif ... #ifdef __cplusplus }; #endif` so it works right in C++. Also in C you need `struct Current ac_curr;` or a `typedef`.

Comment: I'm not aware of any C compiler that has an option to read C++ code and understand it. If it did, it would be called a "C++ compiler".

Comment: and I get it but I am trying to have the work around if possible.

Comment: The work around is to rewrite the header file in the language you are using.  There is not a general way to mix arbitrary C++ code with arbitrary C code in the same translation unit, as they are incompatible languages.

Comment: FYI: [Developing C wrapper API for Object-Oriented C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2045774/7478597)

Answer (score 0):

[ISO C N2176](https://files.lhmouse.com/standards/ISO%20C%20N2176.pdf) §6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers

> 4. For an identifier […] If no prior declaration is visible, or *if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage*.

You can `typedef` that `struct`:

```c
typedef struct Current Current;
#include "somelib.h" // defines struct Current
```

[Example on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/W3rsnnW3Y)