# Empty struct in C vs empty struct in C++

Tags: c++, c, struct, language-lawyer

Why is empty struct in C a constraint violation? Why does this rule get changed in C++?

Are there any historical reasons?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755305/empty-structure-in-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the size of an empty struct in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626446/what-is-the-size-of-an-empty-struct-in-c)

Comment: @Nawaz : This is a different question. The actual question is "why" not "what".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

since you don't have inheritance in C you don't need them. If you just want to have a distinguishable pointer type you can use pointers to incomplete types.

```
struct opaque;

struct opaque* stranger = 0;
```

should work fine.

Comment: I figured you are a macro expert. Could you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355241/generating-function-declaration-using-a-macro-iteration whether there is any improvement possible? Thanks!

Comment: @Johannes, I will be busy this afternoon. Have a look into P99 (through my blog). Or contact me offline tonight.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is this:

In C, there isn't inheritance, templates, and function overloading - three major reasons we use empty structs in C++  - as a base interface, as a template parameter, as a type to help overload resolution.

Can you think of any real use of an empty struct in C?

Comment: Empty structs can be used handle, no? [Handles Comparison: empty classes vs. undefined classes vs. void*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525847/handles-comparison-empty-classes-vs-undefined-classes-vs-void)

Comment: @Nawaz: Maybe, maybe, I specifically mentioned this was just a guess :)

Comment: @Armen: That means, your guess seems to be wrong. Empty structs in C can be used at many occasions, especially where `void*` is used!

Comment: @Nawaz: I disagree: The mere fact that an empty struct CAN be used as a handle doesn't mean it has to. void*, int, etc. are perfectly good handles too. And using empty structs vs void* without inheritance and overloading isn't really any more advantageous.

Comment: @Armen: Handles of type `void*` can be mixed. You can pass handle to pen to a function which accept brush and the compiler would not detect there is a problem. But if you use empty structs, that would give compile time error. Means, handles of `empty_pen*` and `empty_brush*` cannot be mixed. The latter is type-safe!

Comment: @Nawaz: True, but here's a point: The fact that you found a valid reason why emtpy structs are needed and I found one that they aren't CAN mean that when C was standardized no one thought of yours or thought it wasn't a strong enough reason. Because allowing empty structs complicates things a bit - 0 size vs != 0 size etc... So, I agree with your points, but still think my answer isn't plain WRONG. Of course I may be wrong, in which case let's wait for someone to post a far more convincing answer

Comment: @Armen: Standardization complication, or the committee forgot it, is a different thing altogether. All I'm saying is that empty struct has its uses. After all, GDI++ has used it extensively. Even win32 Handle define a member variable called `unused` in HANDLE to avoid zero size issue. If it were allowed, then win32 wouldn't have to define the `unused` member variable in HANDLE struct!

Comment: @nawaz: You don't need it for that anyway, because you can just leave the types undefined. `struct pen; struct brush;`.

Comment: @Armen: Ohh.. how come I forgot that. after all, the link in the first comment also discuss that. :|

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan : I know the post is old but could you plz give me links or more explanation about the reasons about empty structs beside the tag dispatching for overloading.