# C++ all differences between 'struct' and 'class'?

Tags: c++, class, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between struct and class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)

I [used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54585/541686) to [think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585/when-should-you-use-a-class-vs-a-struct-in-c) that the *only* differences between C++ classes were the private-by-default class member access modifiers and the laid-out-like-C guarantee.

*It turns out I was wrong*, because this code doesn't compile:

```
class { int value; } var = { 42 };
```

whereas this does:

```
struct { int value; } var = { 42 };
```

I can't figure out why there's a difference, but there apparently is in Visual C++ 2008:

> error C2552: `'var'` : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list

So, yes, I will ask a many-times-over **duplicate question** (hopefully *without* duplicate answers!):

#### What are ***all*** the differences between structs and classes in C++?

<sup>Of course, feel free to close this if you find that I've missed something in the other questions -- I certainly might have. But I didn't see this being discussed in any of the answers, so I thought I'd ask.</sup>

Comment: "aggregate" means that all members are public.

Comment: The first *is* the only difference between `struct` and `class` but they are crucial to your example. Because `value` is private in the first class the first class is not an aggregate so you can't use aggregate initialization for it. The "laid-out-like-C" guarantee is not a C++ guarantee.

Comment: @Kerrek: "Aggregate" means "public"?! English isn't my first language... now I have a feeling may very well never be. :(

Comment: @Mehrdad: Why "English"? I mean in the C++ standard, the term "aggregate" is thus defined. That has nothing to do with the meanings of "aggregate" in the English language, to my knowledge.

Comment: @Kerrek: Yes, it was indeed my bad to try and use common sense when interpreting the error message, rather than getting a copy of the standard and looking it up in there. Will try and keep this in mind for next time, thanks...

Comment: So... do we close this now as a duplicate? :-)

Comment: @Kerrek: Indeed, please do! x__x If I happen to get a chance to see it at 4 votes then I'll cast the 5th one myself. ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `{}` initializer for aggregates only<sup>1</sup> and the first one is not an aggregate, as it has one `private` data member.

The Standard says in section §8.5.1/1,

> An aggregate is an array or a class (clause 9) with no user-declared
>   constructors (12.1), **no private or protected non-static data members**
>   (clause 11), no base classes (clause 10), and no virtual functions
>   (10.3).

<sup>1. Well, I meant, in C++03, you can use `{}` for aggregates ONLY, but in C++11, you can use `{}` even with non-aggregates (if the non-aggregate class is properly implemented to handle this).</sup>

Also see this for detail answer (on `{}` initializer):

- [What is assignment via curly braces called? and can it be controlled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666321/what-is-assignment-via-curly-braces-called-and-can-it-be-controlled)

Comment: WOWWWW I feel so silly now. Adding `public:` fixes the issue. +1 thanks. *facepalm*

Comment: I'm now kind of wondering -- *why* are we allowed to create a class like that in the first place? There's no legal way to access `x` (not even reflection), so shouldn't the compiler give an error or something?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Actually you can. You can still create instances of such class. The compiler generated *public* constructor is there, and you can use [the instances more like handles!](http://www.ideone.com/c79Gd)

Comment: Use them as handles? Don't you at least need to be able to check them for equality (and differentiate between them)?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Like this : http://www.ideone.com/c79Gd . Just check the addresses. Windows API uses such handles all the time!

Comment: Ohh I guesssssss that's *possible*, though it seems like a really roundabout way of making handles. Oh well, I guess that works.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Also see this : [Handles Comparison: empty classes vs. undefined classes vs. void*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525847/handles-comparison-empty-classes-vs-undefined-classes-vs-void)

Comment: Ah thanks for the link, that's pretty cool actually!

Answer (score 4):

That is **not** a difference between `class` and `struct`, but between *aggregate* and *non-aggregates*. You cannot use the initializer list with a non-aggregate type, but that is unrelated to the `class` or `struct` keyword:

```
class { public: int value; } var = {42};   // compiles
struct { private: int value; } var = {42}; // error
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference **is** between public and private.

Try this instead:

```
class { public: int value; } var = { 42 };
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that members of a class are private as well as any inheritance is private where as a struct is all public.

Someone else will have to give you more specifics though, sorry.